# Dragging a custom pin on a Map View

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I've managed to create a custom image for the pin which is dropped on a map, using MKAnnotationView...

My question is how do I make this custom image draggable on the map? So I can move the image to other parts of the map?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`MKAnnotationView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs. There's a property called `draggable` there, and you have to also implement the `MKAnnotation` protocol `setCoordinate:` method to update the position of the annotation.

Don't forget that it's only supported in iOS 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this tutorial : [mapkit-annotation-drag-and-drop-with](http://hollowout.blogspot.com/2009/07/mapkit-annotation-drag-and-drop-with.html)